# Escape Characters On wget --content-disposition Filenaming

Tags: windows, bash, shell, sh, wget

There are lots of question about Content Disposition, but no one of them match the problem I have. I hope someone here can help me to solve it.

So, I want to download lots of file with wget. I used `--content-disposition` parameter to get good filenaming. But unfortunately when the filename has some special characters, like `\`, `|`, `/`, `:`, `?`, `"`, `*`, `<`, `>`, the file download is escaped.

Lets say, the file I want to download has a filename of **Bussiness Insider: How to Kickstart your Bussiness**. As you can notice the filename has special character of `:`, when I run the script, wget did download the file but the filename return only **Bussiness Insider** with zero size and didn't have any extension.

I'd tried the `--restrict-file-names=windows` and other option avaliable like `-O` with basename but still has no luck.

Here is the script:

```
wget --content-disposition --referer=$url $dl
```

Comment: Can you please share a specific URL that we can test with?

Comment: @darnir Just change the `$url` with [http://it-ebooks.info/book/309/](http://it-ebooks.info/book/309/) and the `$dl` with [http://filepi.com/i/QUqijHf](http://filepi.com/i/QUqijHf). File title on the link is **iPhone: The Missing Manual, 4th Edition**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first **--restrict-file-names=nocontrol**.

If this doesn't work, then for me this worked: **--restrict-file-names=unix** (as I'm on a Linux box OR in Windows using BASH/Cygwin).

You may want --restrict-file-names=windows

If you notice, it'll download the filename with special characters now.

```
$ wget  --restrict-file-names=unix --content-disposition --referer=$url $dl
$ ls -l
total 17740
-rw-r--r-- 1 giga group 18163514 May 10  2014 iPhone: The Missing Manual, 4th Edition.pdf
```

Man for wget shows on this option as:
**--restrict-file-names**=*modes*
           Change which characters found in remote URLs must be escaped during generation of local filenames.  Characters that are restricted by this option are escaped, i.e. replaced with %HH,
           where HH is the hexadecimal number that corresponds to the restricted character. This option may also be used to force all alphabetical cases to be either lower- or uppercase.

```
       By default, Wget escapes the characters that are not valid or safe as part of file names on your operating system, as well as control characters that are typically unprintable.  This
       option is useful for changing these defaults, perhaps because you are downloading to a non-native partition, or because you want to disable escaping of the control characters, or you
       want to further restrict characters to only those in the ASCII range of values.

       The modes are a comma-separated set of text values. The acceptable values are unix, windows, nocontrol, ascii, lowercase, and uppercase. The values unix and windows are mutually
       exclusive (one will override the other), as are lowercase and uppercase. Those last are special cases, as they do not change the set of characters that would be escaped, but rather
       force local file paths to be converted either to lower- or uppercase.

       When "unix" is specified, Wget escapes the character / and the control characters in the ranges 0--31 and 128--159.  This is the default on Unix-like operating systems.

       When "windows" is given, Wget escapes the characters \, |, /, :, ?, ", *, <, >, and the control characters in the ranges 0--31 and 128--159.  In addition to this, Wget in Windows
       mode uses + instead of : to separate host and port in local file names, and uses @ instead of ? to separate the query portion of the file name from the rest.  Therefore, a URL that
       would be saved as www.xemacs.org:4300/search.pl?input=blah in Unix mode would be saved as www.xemacs.org+4300/search.pl@input=blah in Windows mode.  This mode is the default on
       Windows.

       **If you specify nocontrol, then the escaping of the control characters is also switched off. This option may make sense when you are downloading URLs whose names contain UTF-8
       characters, on a system which can save and display filenames in UTF-8 (some possible byte values used in UTF-8 byte sequences fall in the range of values designated by Wget as
       "controls").**

       The ascii mode is used to specify that any bytes whose values are outside the range of ASCII characters (that is, greater than 127) shall be escaped. This can be useful when saving
       filenames whose encoding does not match the one used locally.
```

Comment: Hi Arun, I'd tried all the possible `--restrict-file-names` parameters before and still didn't work. Maybe you have another suggestion? Or another way to cheat this?

Comment: Do this.. it's easy. You know how to get the file name from the URL right? Once you have it, then use that in "wget -O "$filename" $URL" i.e. wget -O "Bussiness Insider: How to Kickstart your Bussiness.pdf" $URL $DL

Comment: When I run this: wget --restrict-file-names=nocontrol --content-disposition --referer=http://it-ebooks.info/book/309 http://filepi.com/i/QUqijHf .... it's giving me the file .. full (the only thing it's doing is it's changing the filename with any special character to it's corresponding HTML/code i.e. _ changed to %3A. Im trying this on a Unix machine

Comment: OK, this worked then as you wanted: wget  --restrict-file-names=unix --content-disposition --referer=http://it-ebooks.info/book/309 http://filepi.com/i/QUqijHf

Comment: Hi Arun, unfortunately, I run the bash from windows machine, and not yet test on unix. I'll give the shot later after setting up the environment... Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Im running the same.. Bash on a Windows machine using Cygwin and it's working .. I updated the answer with the what I got on a Windows machine and Linux machine as well

Comment: Sure, using --restrict-file-names=unix worked (as per my updated answer)

Comment: Ohh man, it worked perfectly! So it's just the matter of wget library. Maybe you want to edit the answer and suggest other readers to use CygWin instead of GnuWin for windows user. Thank you very much. :D